# how can sumvalue and addition null

Tags: oracle

How can I sum `NULL` values?

For example :

```
select sum(nvl(a,0) + nvl(b,0)) s,  c from 
(
select 1 a, null b, 'A' c from dual union 
select null, null b , 'c' c from dual
)
group by c
```

Expected result: when `a` is `NULL`, `b` is `NULL` then `sum(nvl(a,0) + nvl(b,0))` is `NULL`. How can I do this ?

Comment: oracle or sql-server? Please select correct tag.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it.

Comment: sql-server is the same? I ask for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
select Case when (sum(nvl(a,0) + nvl(b,0))) = 0 then null 
else sum(nvl(a,0) + nvl(b,0)) end s,  c 
from 
(
select 1 a, null b, 'A' c from dual union 
select null, null b , 'c' c from dual
)
group by c
```

Comment: If some values are 0 (rather than all `NULL`) then the output will be `NULL` even though there are known values.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `CASE` statement to detect when both `A` and `B` are `NULL`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cce8f/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_data ( a, b, c ) AS
SELECT 1, CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ), 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 'C' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN a IS NULL AND b IS NULL
         THEN NULL
         ELSE nvl(a,0) + nvl(b,0)
         END
       ) AS s,
       c
FROM   sample_data
GROUP BY c
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cce8f/1/0)**:

```
|      S | C |
|--------|---|
|      1 | A |
| (null) | C |
```

Comment: but if i have a lot of column for example sum(a + b + c + d +...) it will difficult to case when?

Comment: @ILoveYou No - just include all the terms: `CASE WHEN a IS NULL AND b IS NULL AND c IS NULL AND d IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE NVL(a,0) + NVL(b,0) + NVL(c,0) + NVL(d,0) END`